# How to use epsilion delta limit definition to proof the limit of x^x as x approaches to 0 is 1

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}{x^x}=1$

What value can the $\delta$ be?

Comment: Why resort to an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument when you could use all of the tools you've been learning for computing limits?

Comment: @Hurkyl Because if I want to use more advanced tools, I think I need to prove it first

Answer (score 0):

How about: pick any $x$ close to $0$, say, $\frac{1}{10^k}$,

$(\frac{1}{10^{k}})^{(\frac{1}{10^{k}})} = 10^{-\frac{k}{10^{k}}}$

Notice how as $k$ grows larger (and your $x$ gets closer to $0$), that exponent (on the RHS) gets closer and closer to zero. What is $\lim_{n\to 0} 10^{n}$?

Comment: It is a good idea, but could you please write it in delta-epsilion format? I cannot find the correct way to represent it in the delta-epsilon way. Thanks.